# python3 + Set function: how to get key and values from dictionary performing set operation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi I have 2 dictonaries as show below (dict1 and dict2) and I need to fetch both keys and values which are in dict2 but not in dict1.
Where the final set snippet prints only keys but not values of it.

## dict1 output: Using default dict while fetching from csv1

```
print(dict1)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {   '1234': [   '1000-A',
                            '1000-A'],
                'X50': ['SRX1500-CHAS', 'SRX1500-DC'],
                'X47': ['SRX1500-CHAS', 'SRX1500-DC'],
                'Serial': ['chassi']})
```

## dict2 output: using default dict while fetching from csv2

```
print(dict2)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {   '1234': [   '1000-A',
                            '1000-A'],
                'X50': ['1100-C', 'DC'],
                'X10': ['1100-C', 'DC'],
                'X100': ['1100-C', 'DC'],
                'Serial': ['chassi']})
```

I am performing set operation and it display only keys but not values.
I need both keys and values in below result.

```
set1 = set(dict1)
set2 = set(dict2)
print(set2 - set1)) # in dict2, not in dict1
[   'X10',
    'X100'
    ]
```

desired o/p should be:

```
[ 'X10': ['1100-C', 'DC'],
'X100': ['1100-C', 'DC']
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there. If `set2 - set1` gives you the keys, then you should just be able to do

```
for key in set2 - set1:
    print(key, dict2[key])
```

However, using sets is a bit unnecessary anyway given that a dictionary's keys *are* a set. Meaning there is only one instance of each key in a dict. I would approach it more like

```
new_dict = {}
for key, value in dict2.items():
    if key not in dict1:
        new_dict[key] = value
```

or using a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {key:value for key, value in dict2.items() if key not in dict1}
```